# Return null default value if no result found

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{  
"value" : "20",
"type" : "square",
"name" : "form1"
}
{
"value" : "24",
"type" : "circle",
"name" : "form2"
}
{
"value" : "12",
"type" : "square",
"name" : "form3"
}
```

I want to extract a document with `name = form2` so I type:

```
db.myCollec.find({"name":"form2"} , {"name":1, "type":1, "_id":0})
```

The result is:

```
{ "name" : "form2", "type" : "circle" }
```

Now if I want to find a document with `name = form4` I type:

```
db.myCollec.find({"name":"form4"} , {"name":1, "type":1, "_id":0})
```

But this returns nothing because there is no document with this name.

However I want the return value to look like this:

```
{ "name" : "form4", "type" : null }
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

Mongodb doesn't produce the result if there is not [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)ed data found with the query.

But you can use [**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) aggregation which processes multiple aggregation pipeline within single stage.

So first use [**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to get the [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)ed documents and use [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)ion if no ([**`$ifNull`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)) data found.

```
let searchTerm = "form2"

db.myCollec.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "data": [
      { "$match": { "name": searchTerm  }},
      { "$project": { "name": 1, "type": 1, "_id": 0 }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": {
      "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$data.name", 0] }, searchTerm ]
    },
    "type": {
      "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$data.type", 0] }, null]
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanx, works great ! I need to work in order to understand how it's working exactly even if I it is clear at 75% ;-)

Comment: Something I have answered before as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52071636/addfields-when-no-match-found

Comment: instead of using `$arrayElemAt` you could simplify and use `$first`

Answer (score -1):

Why you dont check in callback if result==null and create your own empty object?

```
let name = "form4";
db.myCollec.find({"name":name} , {"name":1, "type":1, "_id":0}, function(err, result){
    if(err) {
         // Error handling
         return;
    }
    if (result==null){
        result = {"name":name, "type":null};
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanx, I tried it but nothing appears so I tried to print(result) but still nothing...

Comment: The `find` command returns an array of documents. If no documents are found, `find` will give an empty array as a result, not `null`. So the correct check would be `!result.length` or similar.