# MongoDB: Null check in between Pipeline Stages

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I create a collection like so:

```javascript
db.People.insert({"Name": "John"})
```

and run a simple mongo aggregate, like so:

```javascript
db.People.aggregate([{$match: {Name: "John"}}, {$group: {_id: "null", count: {$sum: 1}}}])
```

This counts all the Johns in the collection and returns this

```json
{ "_id" : "null", "count" : 1 }
```

Which is nice. But if I search for the name "Clarice" that does not exist at all, it returns `null`.

I would like it to return

```json
{ "_id" : "null", "count" : 0 }
```

I have not found a way to achieve this. I would have to include some kind of null-check between the `$match`- and `$group`-stage.

Comment: Check wether the result is a null array like `[]`. That's the only way.

Comment: @AshwanthMadhav: How do I check this? In a separate stage? Or can I somehow integrate "IfNull" into the group stage?

Comment: Are you using loopback ? I will provide ma code for node using loopback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$addFields when no $match found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52071636/addfields-when-no-match-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have have to use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html#facet-aggregation) aggregation along with the operator [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/#ifnull-aggregation). e.g:

```
db.People.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "array": [
      { "$match": { Name:"John" }},
      { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
      }},
      { "$project": { "_id": 0, "count": 1 }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "count": {
      "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$array.count", 0] }, 0 ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Output:

```
{ "count" : 1 }
```

For other name, it should be as follow:

```
{ "count" : 0 }
```

Similar ans at [$addFields when no $match found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52071636/addfields-when-no-match-found)

Comment: This works great on MongoDB and is obviously a correct answer. Sadly I forgot to specify that I am not working on a MongoDB, but a CosmosDB and sadly Microsoft has not implemented the facet-aggregate :/

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `count`

`db. People.count({Name:"John"})`
This will return the exact number.

Otherwise You need to check the result wether it is a empty array. Below are the code for node using loopback,

```
db.People.aggregate([
{$match: {Name: "John"}}, 
 {$group: {_id: "null", count: {$sum: 1}}}
],(err,res)=>{
 if(err) return cb(err)
 if(res.length) return cb(err,res)
 else return cb(err,{_id:null,count:0})
})
```

Comment: This seems like such a simple use case, I can not imagine that there is no solution to it ... :/

Comment: I think you go with `count` without `aggregation`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) in your $match stage.

If you can provide an collecion of examples it's more easy to elaborare an answer on it.

Edit: if you group by Name, result for "John" is one, for "Clarice" is an empty array that is correct, here the aggregation query:

```
db.People.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: { Name: "John" } 

    }, 
    { 
        $group: { _id: "$Name", count: { $sum: 1 } } 
    }
])
```

Comment: I know about "ifNull", but what would be the expression? How do I reference the input to the stage?

Comment: But if I shall count something and there are none entities of this something, then the correct answer is 0. Not `null or `no answer` ...

Comment: An empty array as response for me is fine, because means 0. Null means errors