# return $facet fields if input set is empty

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a reusable pagination pipeline stage like this:

```
const pagination = query => ([ // query are the http request's query params
  {
    $facet: {
      rows: [
        sortOrderStage(query),
        skipStage(query),
        limitStage(query),
      ],
      totalCount: [{ $count: 'count' }],
    },
  },
  { $unwind: '$totalCount' },
  { $addFields: { totalCount: '$totalCount.count' } },
])
```

When I need pagination I append it to an existing pipeline that matches and filters etc.
The problem I have is that when the input set is empty, the $facet part just returns and empty array. What I'd like to see returned in these cases is:

```
{
  rows: [],
  totalCount: 0,
}
```

Currently I process the aggregation results with an extra step:

```
    const data = await Collection.aggregate([ ...pipelines, ...pagination(query)])
    const { rows, totalCount } = data.length
      ? data[0]
      : { rows: [], totalCount: 0 }
```

Is there a way I can modify the pagination stage so I don't need this last step?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your extra step. This is obvious, if there is no data found in aggregation pipeline it will return an empty array. You can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52071636/addfields-when-no-match-found) but of course it is useless in regards of performance.

Comment: Thanks, I am using this pagination for several routes, so I'll need to add the extra step multiple times. My aim is to be DRY, not improve performance. I'll think about the 'somewhat ridiculous' suggestion you link to :)